# Filtered File Listing

Tags: c#, file, filter

i have a project to make and i want in option 2 the user to give an extension/keyword for example and the program to search the directory for this and print all the files that include this extension/keyword and i need some help if it's possible.

Comment: What is your question? Please use LINQ in order to filter/sort/group/etc lists/arrays/IEnumerables/etc. C# is not crappy dinosaur java for God's sake.

Comment: And if you are using a modern version of .NET use [`EnumerateFiles(`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of `GetFiles(` so you don't need to store the entire result in memory before you filter it with LINQ.

Comment: Have you not found any of the provided answers useful?

Answer (score 0):

Then use another overload of the `Directory.GetFiles()` method which accepts a search pattern as a parameter.

Check it out on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/wz42302f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). And here is an example.

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\", "*.exe");
```

Obviously, replace that second argument with a variable name where you store an input from a user.

Answer (score 0):

Or perhaps something like:

```
IEnumerable<string> results = filePaths.Where(x => x.EndsWith(".exe"));
```

Comment: And if the user's input is a keyword instead of an extension? Another query? Or make it `Contains` right away?